# how to check if a MAC address is equal with 0xFF in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> /* A.5.7. */  
#include <stdlib.h> 


int main(void)
{
    unsigned int dig1, dig2, dig3, dig4, dig5, dig6;

    printf("Enter the MAC: ");
    scanf("%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d", &dig1, &dig2, &dig3, &dig4, &dig5, &dig6);

    if (dig1 == 0xFF && dig2 == 0xFF && dig3 == 0xFF && dig4 == 0xFF && dig5 == 0xFF && dig6 == 0xFF)
        printf("Broadcast\n");
    else if (dig1 & 2 == 0)
        printf("Unicast\n");
    else
        printf("Multicast\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably use `%X` instead of `%d` in scanf argument since the input will most probably be in hexadecimal format

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you please explain which behaviour you expect and how does that code deviate from it?

Comment: hello, i am giving this mac address (FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF)  and i want to see if this mac address is equal with 0xFF but it goes in third option where is Multicast and i don't know why

Comment: @Tsevas2001 Jonas Berlin is giving you the answer: _use %X instead of %d in scanf_

Comment: yeah yeah i see it  and i had  this ';' on the last (else). Thank you and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing to an `unsigned int` using format specifier `%d`, and you expect an input of the form `"FF"` to be converted correctly to 0xFF (or dezimal 255).

Two things:

(1) `%d` is for reading signed dezimal values, e.g. -24, or 255, but you store to variable `dig1` of unsigned data type; this is undefined behaviour; for reading in *unsigned decimal* values, use `%u`.

(2) you want to parse input `FF` and convert it to an unsigned integral value; for this, you have to use format `%X`, i.e. `scanf("%X", &dig1)`;

otherwise, if you use `%u` (or `%d`), an input of the form `FF` will be treated as "not matching decimal values", the value of `dig1` remains unchanged.
So if you then compare `dig1` to something, e.g. `if (dig1 == 0xFF)`, then you access an uninitialized value, which is undefined behaviour; one of such behaviour may be that `dig1` contained `0` before the input, what explains that branch 3 of your if..else-sequence is entered. But actually you cannot predict.

Note that `scanf` returns the number of elements parsed successfully. So if you write `int nrOfElemsParsedSuccessfully = scanf("%X:%X:%X:%X:%X", %dig1, ...)`, then you should check if `nrOfElemsParsedSuccessfully == 5`, i.e. if really 5 integral values could be parsed as expected.